# how to create open api?

Tags: php, openapi

I have an entity 'User' and two properties 'name' and 'roles'[enter image description here]. how to make them look like this
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/bTG24.png)

```
 `  /**
  * create user
  * @OA\Tag(name="User")
  * @OA\RequestBody(
  *      required=true,
  *  )
  * @OA\Response(
  *      response=200,
  *      description="User created",
  *      
  *  ),
  * @OA\Response(
  *       response=400,
  *       description="validation error",
  *   ),
  * @return JsonResponse
   */

public function create(Request $request): JsonResponse
{
    $name = $request->get('name');
    $roles = $request->get('roles');
    $user = $this->userUseCase->create($name, $roles);
    return $this->json($user);
}`
```

I don't know what to write in `@OA\RequestBody`.and ideally want to do without  `@ParamConverter` , because I don't like that I have to write it for each controller, because there can be dozens of them

Comment: If you use `return $user` instead of `$this->json($user)` it's still return the same response?

Comment: function createn works correctly, I just don't know what to write in * @OA\RequestBody(
  *      required=true,
  *  )
  * @OA\Response(
  *      response=200,
  *      description="User created",
  *      
  *  ),